# echo with each parameter on its own line

Tags: shell-scripting, ls, echo

I would like an output similar to `ls -1d`, but I don't want to check if each file exists. I would prefer to just list the files. I could use echo, but echo only puts a space between files.

How can I put a return between the files/parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loop.

```
for f in *
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: For those who care, all on one line is `for f in *; do echo "$f"; done`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from your question, you can use `find`

```
find /opt -maxdepth 1
```

For printing file names only

```
find /opt -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

For printing directory names only

```
find /opt -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Comment: +1 You are probably right. Good information.